# Enable PHP error logging with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.5

I can not enable PHP-FPM error logging (NGINX installation) in conjunction with Laravel 5.5 - here is what I did so far in the PHP settings:

```
# /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:
catch_workers_output = yes
# /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini:
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log
```

Then I touched `/var/log/php-errors.log` and made a `chown www-data:www-data` on it.

The strange thing is, that without Laravel, this means on other PHP framework-less installations, the above steps work, that's why I'm assuming it's some kind of Laravel setting preventing the logs to logged? I tried to produce some PHP errors in one of my controllers - but absolutely no logging to `/var/log/php-errors.log`. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Laravel overrides the default exceptions and error handlers meaning that most errors will be handled by laravel itself. However errors like for example out of memory errors will not be handled by laravel (because the exception handler itself needs memory to work and the memory has ran out). Those errors might be handled by the default error handler.

Answer (score 1):

By default laravel logs to the `storage/logs` folder inside your project.

There are [multiple logging configuration options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#configuration) to choose how and where to log.

In Laravel 5.5 and lower you can try setting `APP_LOG` in your `.env` file to `syslog` or `errorlog` to get them in your preferred folder.

In laravel 5.6 this is renamed to `LOG_CHANNEL` in your `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked it - there are no PHP errors. It's "only" the frameworks exceptions inside.

Comment: What kind of error did you trigger? By default also php errors such as `syntax error, unexpected: x` should be logged in `storage/logs/`.

Comment: Excuse me my fault. Indeed it also contains the PHP errors.